# How to modify tags in Tkinter Canvas by events

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, event-handling

I am programmatically adding tag_binds to all objects on my canvas that have the tag "tag":

```
self.canvas.tag_bind("tag","<Button 2>",self.tag_highlight)
```

`self.canvas` contains all the objects that the user has added (all tagged with "tag".

However, in `tag_highlight`, I would simply like to have a handle on the actual element within the canvas. `event.widget` doesn't seem to help, its just a tuple of 4 floats that I cannot link to any canvas item. I have tried to use the following, to no avail:

```
self.canvas.find_closest(event.x,event.y)
```

What I would like to do, is have a handle like:

```
t=self.canvas.getitem(event.widget)
```

so that I can use it for example in:

```
self.canvas.Move(t,30,20)
print self.canvas.coords(t)
```

and so forth.
Maybe I am just missing the obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tag "current", which refers to the "current" object. The current object is described like this in the [official tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M8):

> The tag current is managed automatically by Tk; it applies to the
>   current item, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the
>   position of the mouse cursor (different item types interpret this in
>   varying ways; see the individual item type documentation for details).
>   If the mouse is not in the canvas widget or is not over an item, then
>   no item has the current tag.

Comment: Bryan: I realize this is an old question & answer, but in the linked tk documentation it says that a tag string "may take any form except that of an integer". However, in Python 3.7.1 using a tag like that (created via a `str(intval)`) seems to work fine. Are the tk docs out-of-date or just wrong?

Comment: @martineau: the reason you can’t use an integer is that when you try to use it later the canvas will interpret it as an item id.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps that's true with respect to event handling, but in my own code that's using it later to modify an existing object via a `Canvas.itemconfig()` call, it appears to work properly.

Comment: @martineau: you might want to double-check your code. It's been this way since tk was invented, and they take backwards-compatibility very seriously. Using 3.7.1, I just created a canvas object with an integer as a tag and could not configure it with that tag.

Comment: I think starting allow it _would_ be backwards compatible, since no one should have been doing so. Not much to review really, as those parts of the code are relatively simple. I've upload a copy of the [script](https://pastebin.com/hspLidHs), if you'd like to see proof—there are only two statements involved—just search for `str(index)`.

Comment: @martineau: That code is not doing quite what you think it's doing, you have a simple off-by-one error. You can see this fairly easy by putting in special code for when index is zero in `update_canvas`. For example, when it's zero, unconditionally set the fill color to bright green and you'll see that no square ever turns green because even though there's an item with a tag of zero (the upper-left corner), tkinter interprets that as an index and there is no item with an index of zero.

Comment: @martineau: As for the backwards compatibility issue, the problem is that if you do something like `canvas.itemconfigure(12, ...)` how would tkinter know if you're wanting to change the item with an index of 12 or an item with a tag of 12? Tkinter can't distinguish the two, so it always treats integers as element indexes.

Comment: We're talking about starting to support something like `canvas.itemconfigure("12", ...)` (or `str(12)`). If it never worked before, doesn't seem like starting to allow it would break anything—old or new.

Comment: @martineau: it _will_ break all sorts of things. That's because `canvas.itemconfigure("12", ...)` already does something - it configures the item with an index of "12" (under the hood, the tcl/tk engine doesn't distinguish between a string or an integer). If it suddenly changed to configure an item with a tag of "12", all of the code that depended on it configuring an item with an index of "12" would break.